# Does icalendar support HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, icalendar, rfc5545

I am attempting to create a ICalendar with a html description using the X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html: but it does not appear to support inline CSS for layout/styling is there anyway of making CSS work within an icalendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RFC 5545 (the iCalendar specification) allows you to use HTML, but that's a different thing from the calendar clients supporting it.  I suspect that you'll find it rare that any of the non-browser-based calendars will do so.

Answer (score 3):

As opposed to what jgm implied, the RFC5545 does not have provisions for html.

The only back-door is via the `ALTREP` parameter (see [RFC for more details](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.1))

However this implicitly refers to icalendar invitation sent by emails (as it is most often using the CID URI), but other URI like HTTP(S) could also be used though less often so.

Also you should be aware that **RFC5545** compliance is **far from complete** even from the most prominent calendars (google calendars for instance only aims at RFC2445 (which was obsoleted by RFC5545),...)

Also the `X-ALT-DESC` is a MSFT specific extension (see [MSND on iCalendar/X-ALT-DESC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee237480%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)) which.

So coming back to your question, which calendars do you want to support your .ics file and be able to render in?

Answer (score 0):

hcalendar converts to icalendar; hcalendar is a microformats icalendar implementation. check out more http://microformats.org/wiki/hcalendar